# No analytics cookies is set upon a consent was updated

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-talk

I am using the Google Tag Manager with a single tag referencing a default Google Analytics script. My solution is based on the information from these resources:

- https://www.iubenda.com/en/help/27137-google-consent-mode
- https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/consent-settings-google-tag-manager/
- https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/consent-mode-google-tags/

The code is simple ([commit](https://github.com/literakl/mezinamiridici/commit/c2844eb54e9ccfcb919d40ef0f2f2be024466638)):

index.html: define `gtag()` and set denied as a default for all storages

```
  <script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag() { window.dataLayer.push(arguments); }
    gtag('consent', 'default', {
      ad_storage: 'denied',
      analytics_storage: 'denied',
      personalization_storage: 'denied',
      functionality_storage: 'granted',
      security_storage: 'granted',
      wait_for_update: 400,
    });
```

Then load a user configuration from the `localStorage` and call update:

```
handleCookies(preferences) {
  console.log('handleCookies callback');
  gtag('consent', 'update', {
    ad_storage: preferences.ad,
    analytics_storage: preferences.analytics,
    personalization_storage: preferences.personalization,
  });
  console.log(window.dataLayer);
},
```

So far so good because I see the event queue is updated in `dataLayer`:

[image: chrome console]

As the consent is set I anticipate the the cookies will be set for the Google Analytics now. But they are missing. What stupid mistake have I done?

[image: cookies box]

[image: GTM configuration]

Comment: silly me, it seems to be related to sending true instead of granted

Comment: Yes, you should use `granted` and `denied` rather than `true` and `false`.

Comment: True. I haven't noticed I am sending the boolean. Default object was correct. Stupid mistake.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `update` command happens after the GTM container snippet is rendered by the browser, so the update command is processed only after the All Pages trigger has already been processed.

You need to either delay your tags to fire on a later trigger (e.g. DOM Ready) or change how your script works to push the `'update'` command sooner.

Alternatively, you can use the Consent Mode tag template found in the template gallery to orchestrate everything through GTM. The template uses GTM's synchronous consent APIs which ensure that the consent state is applied immediately rather than only once the `dataLayer` queue is processed.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I think I have finished my solution. GA will generate client side cookies only once a user provided a consent. So far so good. But GA will never send the cookie value. Am I missing something? More details in my answer. The app is deployed here: https://beta.mezinamiridici.cz/. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

From your screenshot, `gtm.js` is executed before the `update` of the consent mode so the pageview continues to be sent to Google Analytics as denied.

The update must take place before gtm.js

Comment: I think it should not work this way. The articles I read state I should set the defaults before gtm.js is loaded and push the update when there are consent changes. A user will confirm the consent cookie dialog seconds or minutes after the page is loaded. There is the Update message for such purpose. GTM must load all scripts before the consent dialog is displayed.

Comment: sure, before the consent you will lose the data but after the consent, as I wrote, the update must take place before gtm.js

Comment: I still did not get your point. gtm.js is loaded once as soon as possible. Would you be more concrete and provide step by step instructions what shall I do when the page is loaded and user accepts the consent screen?

Comment: You can send an update but if you want send the pageviews before cookie accento you have to define a cookie policy, i.e. anonimyzeIp and start with analytics_storage granted, bit it is legal question bot technical issue.

Comment: Thank you for your effort but there is some misunderstanding. My english may be too poor. I failed to explained you that gtm.js is loaded before the consent and therefore the update message can occur afterwards.

Answer (score 3):

As a note for my silly future myself I will write some findings and notes there.

1. follow Simo's advices though it might not be easy to understand without a prior subject orientation
2. define `gtag()` function and set the default settings prior gtag initialization
3. the first visit shall set `denied` for `ad_storage`, `analytics_storage` and `personalization_storage`
4. if it is a returning visit it is a good idea to set the defaults according to a user's content
5. but hey, you can send the `update` message later, even in a Vue component's `mounted` method. A value in `wait_for_update` might be useful there because you want to initialize Google Analytics with cookies rather then without them.
6. Google Analytics sends https://www.google-analytics.com/g/collect request. Take a look to payload, `gcs: G100` is sent when the cookies consent is missing.
7. Once a user accepts the cookies, send new consent values in the `update` message. The values are `denied` / `granted`, not `true` / `false`, you fool!
8. The GA cookies are created at this moment. But they are not sent to server, sorry, your turn is over. Well, if a user does some tracked action like a scrolling a page, the `collect` will be sent again with `gcs: G111`. I am bit surprised that neither the request not the response holds any cookie. Why?
9. Once I reload the page and all storages are granted by default, `gcs: G111` is still present in GA's collect but the page's existing cookies are not present in the request. Why?

[image]

Comment: Because hit with G100 are not shown in the report and clientid changes.

Comment: Really? Chrome dev tool presents all requests. GA shall use cookies when the consent is granted, shall not? See https://beta.mezinamiridici.cz/

Comment: Hit is sent to Google Analytics but you can't see it in the report. Google Analytics will use these hits for modeling, so probably in the future something will be seen in the reports but not today.

Comment: You mean GA report. I am talking about HTTPS request generated by GA javascript which does not contain any cookie though the cookies consent was recorded by Google tag manager.

Comment: When analytics is granted the clientid (cookie value) alias cid in the request is fixed and not changes in the next requests.

Comment: Ahh, so GA is sending client id as a request parameter instead of cookies. I was not aware of this. So when cid is present, my setup is correct. Great to know. Thank you

Comment: leaving this here in case it helps anyone. i found this which is contrary to gtag examples elsewhere: "For a gtag implementation: Find the code that calls the API gtag('config', 'AW-xxxx') and make sure the gtag('consent', 'default') or gtag('consent', 'update') commands fire before any gtag('config') commands. Once updated, check if the consent states are present in the Config event." also found what seems to be a bug. to fix the bug i have duplicate code before the config and before script src exactly as shown in my next comment.

Comment: bug fix: https://support.cookiehub.com/article/167-issues-with-default-consent-state-in-google-tag-manager-may-2022

Comment: gtag placement link: https://support.google.com/tagassistant/answer/12005833?hl=en#zippy=%2Cconsent-mode-is-not-detected-on-some-of-your-pages

Comment: so order is: window.datalayer -> func gtag() -> gtag(consent) -> script src -> gtag(js) -> gtag(config). where consent have default values. after consent verified, i call gtag(consent, update) with the new values and seems to work fine. not sure why order is different when google initially gives you the code block to paste.